# AC air compressor voltage spikes

Tags: ac, spike

I have a "mgf compressors" named MINI BEV that generates voltage spikes up to about 500Vpk (353Vrms) on the 230Vrms AC lines. My question is if this is normal? I understand that its an inductive spike coming from the motor, but it seems like nothing has been done to prevent the spikes to enter the AC network.

It says that it is CE approved. Below is a figure of my measurement.

[image]

Comment: How did you measure 500 Vpk?

Comment: Added figure now.

Comment: Did the contractor shut on/off at the time of the disturbance?

Comment: It shut off. But it have also happened when turning on for some reason.

Comment: RC filter across the contactor?

Comment: Yes, will have to try that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Measured at what bandwidth / with what instrument?  It's probably more than that; the pulses are very short, and can have significant ringing.

Normal, sure. Mechanical contacts switching inductive loads typically generates an EFT (electrical fast transient) burst.

Is it good, proper? Within regulations?  Depends.  Simple electromechanical equipment generally does not require it.  Conversely, most equipment is required to meet IEC 61000-4-4 at 1-2kV test levels, which covers for most instances of this.

If the noise is annoying, or interfering with other devices, you can put a snubber across the switch.  Typical value being 0.1µF + 100Ω, which usually doesn't interfere with other operation of the equipment (it does let through some current when the switch is off, which doesn't play well with small motors and electronic loads).